# Fabric JS: Line drawing with borders

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

Is it possible to draw a line with borders in fabric JS? I'm looking to draw a line with the only stroke value and I want the fill to remain white so that it looks like a line with borders. As far I referred the documentation I guess it's not possible fabricJS, Is there any alternative to achieve that requirement using fabricJS.
http://jsfiddle.net/fy6b2rso/1/

```
var newLine = new fabric.Line([400,100,150,300],{
        stroke: "#000000",
        strokeWidth: 11,
});

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(newLine);
canvas.renderAll();
```

[image]

Comment: You can use fabric.Rect instead.

Comment: post some samples if possible @Durga

Comment: Like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1puvrh3f/)